# jQuery Ajax request not working as I intended

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iis

I'm just testing Ajax request. It seems the request was sent successfully but not getting any contents back when it is supposed to. Can anyone help me with this?
I'm using IIS to deploy my app on localhost.

And yes, I have added Module Mapping wizard, with following values:
Request path: *.php
Module: FastCgiModule
Executable: C:\php\php-cgi.exe (or the path to your PHP executable)
Name: PHP via FastCGI

[Request sent successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY0HJ.png)

head.html

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
<title>Comments</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  Bootstrap Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<!-- DataTables js -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!-- main js -->
<!-- <script src='main.js' defer></script> -->
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <? include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes/head.html"; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api2.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'fn': 'test',
                    'returnJson': true
                },
                success: function(d) {
                    console.log(d)
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

api2.php

```
<?php

function test() {
    return 'hello';
}

?>
```

Added Module Mapping wizard, enter the following values:

Request path: *.php
Module: FastCgiModule
Executable: C:\php\php-cgi.exe (or the path to your PHP executable)
Name: PHP via FastCGI
Click Request Restrictions, select the File or folder radio button, and then click OK.

Comment: I don't see the bit of your PHP code that actually calls the `test()` function, is that what your "module mapping" is supposed to do? What is in your `$_POST` array when it actually arrives in `api2.php`?

Comment: Does your ajax work fine locally? Or does the problem appear only when it is published to IIS? Are there any error messages in the console?